# SwiftUI: Tap target for Navigation Bar Button misaligned after dismissing a sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am noticing a rather strange, possibly buggy behavior in SwiftUI using iOS 13.3.1 and earlier. To demonstrate, this very simple scenario:

**Full sample code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("ParentView")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.showingSheet = true }) { Text("Show") })
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) { SheetView() }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet content")
            Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) { Text("Hide") }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**To reproduce:**

1. Launch the app on iOS 13.4.1
2. Tap the "Show" button
3. (The sheet shows, as expected)
4. Dismiss the sheet using the "Hide" button
5. (The sheet is dismissed, as expected)
6. Try to show the sheet again, using the "Show" button

**Expected result**: The sheet shows again.

**Actual result**: The tap target of the "Show" button is shifted some pixels to the bottom, resulting in the action not triggering. This can also be observed in the View Hierarchy Debugger:

[image: Misaligned Views]

**Other observations:**

- This does not happen when dismissing the sheet by dragging it to the bottom of the screen
- This occurs only if large navigation item titles are activated for the hosting view, it's fine when using an inline title

---

So now I'm here wondering: Am I making a mistake, or is this an actual SwiftUI bug? If so, is there an easy workaround? I searched SO for similar issues, but didn't come across any that were identical.

*Edit:* I filed this with Apple as Radar Feedback FB7560960 in the meantime.

*Edit 2:* Still happening in 13.4.1.

Comment: I had the same issue when presenting & dismissing `UIViewController` with the UIKit way. (iOS 15.2) As a workaround, I removed the toolbar buttons just 1ms after dismissing the view controller. It's ugly and the toolbar buttons sometimes blink when dismissing but better than nothing, I think...

Comment: Still getting this with Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.2  The only solution that works for me is to make the modals present as full screen.
This also seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485329/swiftui-modal-presentation-works-only-once-from-navigationbaritems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but adding
`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`
to `contentView` seems to fix it.

Comment: Indeed! Seems like this triggers a re-render for the ContentView when dismissing the modal, fixing the bug along the way. More a work-around than a solution in my eyes, but does the trick! Thank you.

Comment: That did not seem to work for me. With `contentView` you mean `ContentView` ? The struct that gets generated when creating a new SwiftUI project which sits as the initial view of the App?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, but funnily enough, was only able to reproduce it on some simulators/devices running iOS 14.4 and 15.0 - not on iOS 13.3.

The only workaround that solved it for me was to change the presentation mode from `.automatic` (i.e. `.pageSheet` on iOS >=13) to `.fullScreen` (the previous default). I suppose the equivalent in pure SwiftUI would be to use `.fullScreenCover` instead of `.sheet`.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 16+**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
  SheetView()
   .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.999)])
 }
```

Comment: Essentially disabling  the presentation Detents keeps the buttons from misaligning.  This worked well!  It wouldn't be needed If Apple would fix this years old bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I got out of it.
I close the sheet view when my app will enter in background.
It's not the best solution but it allows me to keep the swipe gesture

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
               
               showingSheet = false

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, I was still having this issue in Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.2. I noticed that by entering and leaving a textfield on the view the buttons tap targets would magically fix themselves. So I tried this after the modal is dismissed:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

...and it works  A bit of a monstrous hack, but it's the only thing I found that would solve the problem.