# Modal view presented in navigation button issue

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sheet View content")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sheet View"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Dismissing sheet view...")
//                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
//                    self.showSheetView.toggle()
                    self.showSheetView = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @State var showSheetView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("first")
        }.navigationBarTitle("asdf").navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.showSheetView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Sheet View")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
            SheetView(showSheetView: self.$showSheetView)
        })
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheetView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()) {
                Text("ds")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SheetView is presented successfully in ContentView2. And then i click Done button to dismiss and try to show it again. It will always fail. But when i place the launch button not in the navigation bar, the issue not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known defect, but not with binding - with layout of navigation bar items...

Here is workaround

```
.navigationBarTitle("asdf").navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    self.showSheetView.toggle()
}) {
    Text("Show Sheet View").padding()   // << add padding !!
```

You can find more details and alternate solution in [SwiftUI modal presentation works only once from navigationBarItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492031/12299030)

Comment: It works. Using view debugger to address the issue  is very smart.