# SwiftUI NavigationItem doesn't respond

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift4

When I click on the left arrow it should dismiss the view, but only the UI responds as the button being clicked and the view pushed by a NavigationLink is not dismissed...

The same view pushed by another NavigationLink in another view works perfectly, but when pushed by this NavigationLink, I click on the left arrow, only 1 in 20 times it dismisses the view. Is it bug in SwiftUI again? Is there a workaround?

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import struct Kingfisher.KFImage

struct SearchView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @State var typedSearchValue = ""
    @State var createNewPost = false
    @State var showMessaging = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo : UserData
    
    @Binding var switchTab: Int
    
    @State var text : String = ""
    @State var foundUsers: [FetchedUser] = []
    
    @State var showAccount = false
    @State var fetchedUser = FetchedUser()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
                // navigate to that user's profile << the problem navlink
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    UserAccountView(fetchedUser: self.$fetchedUser, showAccount: self.$showAccount)
                        .environmentObject(self.userInfo)
                        .environmentObject(FetchFFFObservable())
                    ,isActive: self.$showAccount
                ){
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                
                //...
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    MessagingMainView(showMessaging: self.$showMessaging)
                        .environmentObject(UserData())
                        .environmentObject(MainObservable()),
                               isActive: self.$showMessaging
                ){
                    Text("")
                }
                
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    SearchBarMsg(text: $text, foundUsers: $foundUsers)
                        .environmentObject(userInfo)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    VStack{
                        if text != ""{
                            
                            List(foundUsers, id: \.username){ user in
                                FetchedUserCellView(user: user)
                                    .environmentObject(self.userInfo)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.fetchedUser = user
                                        self.showAccount = true
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            
                            //....
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarColor(.titleBarColor)
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
}
```

Navigates to this view, and the button in navigationItems doesn't work, although the UI responds:

```
struct UserAccountView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    
 //...
    
    @Binding var showAccount : Bool
    

    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //.....
            
        }
            
            .navigationBarColor(.titleBarColor)
            
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(fetchedUser.username), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                //this button doesn't work!
                self.showAccount = false
                
            }, label: {
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 15)
                   
                
            })).accentColor(.white)
        )
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I re-enabled the default button and then that works fine... The trailing navigation item button still takes a few clicks to take effect... I have no idea why ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I assume it could be the same as explained & solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492031/12299030.