# SwiftUI NavBar button not working while timer updates view

Tags: swiftui

Seems there's an issue triggering the NavBar button while timer updates the view.
In the example below, the Close button works, but the NavBar button Cancel, doesn't.
Any idea why? Or how to fix

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isPresented = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            ModalView()
        })
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    private var monitorTimer: Timer?
   
    @Published var someThing: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        startMonitoring()
    }
    
    func startMonitoring() {
        monitorTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.someThing.toggle()
        })
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                if model.someThing {
                    Text("True")
                } else {
                    Text("False")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Close")
                })
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Modal")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug is more global - Cancel does not work even if you remove that if/else block at all. In debugger I do not get into button action block on breakpoint, so it is deep in SwiftUI. And it is not https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492031/12299030, because as seen from view hierarchy debug the rects are now are layout correctly. I recommend to submit feedback to Apple. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tested workaround (Xcode 12 / iOS 14). The solution is to separate subviews to avoid global refresh, like below

**Note: by the way - don't forget to stop timer on close modal, because state object remains alive, so now your timer runs even after sheet get closed**

```
struct ModalView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        InternalModal().environmentObject(model)
    }
}

struct InternalModal: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                UpdatingView()

                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Close")
                })
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Modal")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    })
        }
    }
}

struct UpdatingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        if model.someThing {
            Text("True")
        } else {
            Text("False")
        }
    }
}
```