# Why the ToolbarItem Button is not tappable?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a navigationView with the ToolbarItem containing a button.
**This button is not tappable correctly**. To move to the next screen i have to tap underneath.
As you can see from the *Debug View Hierarchy*:
[image]

Here is how i am adding the button to the toolbar:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack { ... }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Format"), displayMode: .inline)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button("Next") {
                setCanvas()
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

This view is being pushed with a *NavigationLink*

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492031/12299030?

Comment: Yes thank you, I will post the solution here

Comment: Looks like your solution is not different from Asperi's mentioned answer, in this case you should delete both this answer and the question, because it's really a duplicate

Comment: In my opinion someone could find this post with this different title and description... I'm not a moderator here, so I could delete with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add an .id to the Button in order to force the Button to render it self. I was showing a modal before this and it had that position.

```
var body: some View {
ZStack { ... }
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Format"), displayMode: .inline)
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("Next") {
            setCanvas()
        }
        .id(UUID())
    }      
}
```

}